# Check whether a test case already exists before creating it - TFS 2018

Tags: api, testing, tfs, automation, postman

I am creating a test case in TFS 2018 using postman like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://TFSURL:443/DefaultCollection/PROJECT/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version=4.1' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
  -d '[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
        "from": null,
        "value": "TEST\\Automation"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
        "from": null,
        "value": "TEST\\Sprint 8"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "Sample task"
    },
    { 
        "op": "add", 
        "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
        "value": "<steps id=\"0\">
        <step id=\"1\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 1</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 1</parameterizedString><description/></step>
        <step id=\"2\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 2</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 2</parameterizedString><description/></step>
        <step id=\"3\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 3</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 3</parameterizedString><description/></step>
        <step id=\"4\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 4</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 4</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"
    } 
]'
```

How can I check before sending this request that this test exist so that I can update it instead of creating a new one every time?

I was expecting to do it by :

- searching the name of the automation which should be unique in tfs (method name from automation script) and see if it returns something

It seems like in tfs there is a way to do a request to get all work items but I am not sure if you can return based on the title field of the item. ([Help page on how to do this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get_list_of_work_items))

I tried to use the search api to return the results if anything with that name exists in tfs but I am getting an error message which I don't know how to resolve

```
  curl -X POST \
      'https://TFSURL:443/DefaultCollection/PROJECT/_apis/search/workitemsearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[
    {
        "searchText": "Sample task",
        "$skip": 0,
        "$top": 1,
        "filters": {
            "System.AreaPath": [
                "TEST\\Automation"
            ]
        },
        "$orderBy": [
            {
                "field": "system.id",
                "sortOrder": "ASC"
            }
        ],
        "includeFacets": true
    }
]'
'
```

Response:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question in case someone else needs it, as I have read you can't do this with just a single or two different API calls. for the following solution i have created multiple REST API request to TFS and called/processed them with Python >3.

What I have done in order to update a test case if it exist or create a new one it if it is not:

- Create in tfs a query which returns all test cases
- Update query using an API request and the key of the query you have created (i specified iteration and team specifically in the body of the request) ([help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/update?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#update_a_query))
- Create an API request to get the result of that query ([help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1))
- In a loop i was iterating over all the test case ids the query has returned
- In the same loop I have used the test case id to access with a request that specific work item ([help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get_list_of_work_items))
- I then compared the title of the returned item versus the title that i want to create from my automate script (ClassName_MethodName)
- If those titles where the same I do a request to update that test case using the test id i got and then break from the loop
- If the titles were different i create a new test case and then break from the loop

I know this is not the fastest solution but at least it is working!
If there is another way which is easier and faster I am more than happy to follow it.